# Is it possible to use generic DataContract's from the client end?

Tags: c#, generics, datacontract, wcf

I know when you create a service you can create a generic DataContract:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Get{0}Request")
public sealed class GetItemRequest<T>
    where T : class, new() { ... }

[DataContract(Name = "Get{0}Response")
public sealed class GetItemResponse<T>
    where T : class, new() { ... }

[ServiceContract]
public void MyService : IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    GetItemResponse<Foo> GetItem(GetItemRequest<Foo> request);
}
```

This generates a `GetFooRequest` and `GetFooResponse` definition for my WSDL. Now, what I'm curious about is if it is possible to go in the other direction?

Is it possible to create a client that uses the Generic DataContracts and pass those to the server as a concrete object? I attempted this after adding a Service Reference and it didn't really work out so well. So this is more of me wondering if there is any way (even if it means not adding a Service Reference) to do this?

Comment: I confess that this feature (as described [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045.aspx)) is *not* one I had seen previously. Interesting.

Comment: @Marc: Yea, but it's only half-useful. The other team in charge of the `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract` classes slacked off when it came to generating the Name values and don't do the nice checks for generics that `DataContract` does, hence why you can not create Concretely defined generic Operation/Service contracts! Maybe C# 5? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, WCF is going to look at the contract class. If that is generated from WSDL/MEX it won't have this (since this isn't how it is expressed in the metadata) - but if your client has the code as above, then sure it should work fine.

If you add a *library* reference (i.e. a dll / project reference) to your DTO dll from the client, and ensure WCF has shared-assemblies enabled, it should work. If it still baulks, then cheat: use a service reference *just to get the config data*. Then delete the service reference but keep the configuration (those config files are a pain otherwise). Then it *should* locate the type from the library.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem. The generic class is in it's own namespace `MyNamespace.Common`, and the concrete definitions are generated in a different namespace `MyNamespace.Services.XService`. So, on the client end I'm still leaving the generic class in a `MyNamespace.Common` definition, hence I don't have a concrete definition in the correct namespace to be used. Basically, it isn't as useful as I thought because I still have to create a concrete type `GetFooRequest : GetItemRequest<T>`, add a DataContract attribute to it (so I might as well add the Name/Namespace).

Comment: It seems that even though it's possible, it doesn't seem as useful going from the client to the server as it does from the server to the client. I'll have to play around with this some more.