# Different SOAP Headers in request/response using Message Contracts

Tags: wcf

I'm building some services which have a common header. This header has a certain layout in the request, and a different one in the response (i.e., there are two classes).

However, when I add a reference or use svcutil, the proxy is generated with the same header in both request and response types.

For instance:

```
[MessageContract]
class Contract<THeader, TBody>
{
    [MessageHeader] public THeader Header { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember] public TBody Body { get; set; }
}

class MyRequestHeader
{
    public string RequestorId { get; set; }
}

class MyResponseHeader
{
    public string ErrorMessage  { get; set; }
}
```

The OperationContract is something like:

```
[OperationContract]
public Contract<MyResponseHeader, ResponseBody> Process(Contract<MyRequestHeader, RequestBody> data);
```

The proxy becomes something like:

```
var client = new ...; 
var header = new MyRequestHeader(); 
var body = new RequestBody();

**ResponseBody** 

response = client.Process(ref header, body);
```

As you can see, the header (Request) is passed as ref; That probably means WCF is having this header as the same in request and response. And the MyResponseHeader disappears.

Anyone can shed some light on the subject?

Comment: Can you show us the wsdl that is generated for this service?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your setup. I had to mark sone types `public`, but was able to create a service for it. After using `svcutil.exe` to create a proxy i got the same result as you (Response message has Header of type MyRequestHeader).

Comment: Can it have anything to do with [known types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/darrylru/archive/2011/05/04/datacontract-serialization-with-generics-amp-read-only-properties.aspx)? And do you have a [library reference to the common data classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685456/is-it-possible-to-use-generic-datacontracts-from-the-client-end) and checked that one (or include all in project) at "Reuse Types" while generating the service reference?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have them set to "Reuse Types", but there's no direct reference to the project where those types were defined;

Answer (score 6):

There is something strange going on here.

I tried to reproduce your problem, and got the following results (i had to mark some types `public`, and added `[DataContract]` to your header classes).

Here is a view of the WSDL:

[image: WSDL]

The generated code (svcutil 4.0.30319.18046) uses `MyRequestHeader` in the Response message as well:

[image: Client code]

This is caused by the following XSD:

[image: XSD]

As you can see there is only one instance generated for the "Header" class.

I tried creating types for the generic classes, as follows:

```
[MessageContract]
public abstract class Contract<THeader, TBody>
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public THeader Header { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public TBody Body { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name="RequestHeader")]
public class MyRequestHeader
{
    public string RequestorId { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "ResponseHeader")]
public class MyResponseHeader
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class RequestContract : Contract<MyRequestHeader, string>
{ }

[MessageContract]
public class ResponseContract : Contract<MyResponseHeader, string>
{ }

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ResponseContract Process(RequestContract data);
}
```

But that did not fix the problem, the generated client ResponseContract still is generated using a Header of type RequestHeader.

Even changing the service code to use two diffrent message contracts:

```
[DataContract(Name="RequestHeader")]
public class MyRequestHeader
{
    public string RequestorId { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "ResponseHeader")]
public class MyResponseHeader
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class RequestContract<TBody>
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public MyRequestHeader Header { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public TBody Body { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract]
public class ResponseContract<TBody>
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public MyResponseHeader Header { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public TBody Body { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ResponseContract<string> Process(RequestContract<string> data);
}
```

does not solve the problem:

[image: Client code]

Even removing all shared inheritance and generics as follows:

```
[DataContract(Name="RequestHeader")]
public class MyRequestHeader
{
    public string RequestorId { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "ResponseHeader")]
public class MyResponseHeader
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(WrapperName="RequestMessage")]
public class RequestContract
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public MyRequestHeader Header { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(WrapperName = "ResponseMessage")]
public class ResponseContract
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public MyResponseHeader Header { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ResponseContract Process(RequestContract data);
}
```

still results in the RequestHeader being used in the ResponseMessage.

I think the answer lies somewhere in [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx):

> **WSDL Considerations**
>
> When generating a Web Services Description
>   Language (WSDL) contract from a service that uses message contracts,
>   **it is important to remember that not all message contract features are
>   reflected in the resulting WSDL** [sic]. Consider the following points: WSDL
>   cannot express the concept of an array of headers. When creating
>   messages with an array of headers using the
>   MessageHeaderArrayAttribute, the resulting WSDL reflects only one
>   header instead of the array.
>
> The resulting WSDL document may not reflect some protection-level
>   information.
>
> The message type generated in the WSDL has the same name as the class
>   name of the message contract type.
>
> When using the same message contract in multiple operations, multiple
>   message types are generated in the WSDL document. The names are made
>   unique by adding the numbers "2", "3", and so on, for subsequent uses.
>   When importing back the WSDL, multiple message contract types are
>   created and are identical except for their names.

Comment: Thank you very, very much... That's the same problem. I do believe it's a restriction from the framework, but I have no idea why that is so. I wonder if no one ever tried this before...